# Spouse's name issue

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a small issue with my name mentioned in my wife's passport spouse name column. It's mentioned as (abc xyz) but my name in my passport is (abc xyz ghi). I am an Indian citizen.

Will it be an issue when applying for a tourist visa for any Schengen country? I already have a ten-year USA visa.

If I am asked to provide a marriage certificate, my wife's maiden name is mentioned on it and now it's changed after marriage with my name as the last name. Will it be an issue?

Comment: In most Western cultures, traditionally the wife takes her husband's last name after marriage, so I can't imagine that a name change, especially with a marriage certificate on hand would be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Standard European passports don't even include spouse's name on it, so very likely they only check the marriage certificate.

Also, my experience in western Europe is that people care very little about extra surnames. If you have a matching surname in one document it doesn't matter if there are additional surnames in another.

Comment: so i dont need to get an affadavit from. the indian embassy saying my wifes maiden name in the marriage certificate is changed to her new name in the passport. i was thinking of doin it incase some country would ask for it

Comment: I can't say for sure for every country, but very likely is not going to happen in Europe.

Comment: what abt the spouse name in my wife's passport? my complete name isnt mentioned. just two out of three names there. also i wanted to knw if getting paid by cheque is an issue? lot of ppl these days get banl transfer for salaries. will it be an issue for visa as in to prove a valid source of income?